# What does a node do if the two selected tips it has to validate are inconsistent?

Tags: iri-node, double-spending, validation

Every article or blog post that I found only goes to the point where a node has selected two tips via the MCMC walk and checked them for consistency (and then states that if they are inconsistent the network will achieve consensus on one of the transactions/subtangles).

But what *does* the node actually do now when it has those conflicting transactions? Will it try to find two new and unconflicting transactions? Randomly (or otherwise) decide for just one of the two tips?

Hope someone can solve that riddle for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not remembering wrong, when a discrepancy is detected the node runs again the MCMC algorithm and chooses two other tips.

The inconsistent tips will remain on the tangle.

The growth of the tangle will (hopefully) confirm only one of the two tips, the other will be on an orphaned branch and will never be confirmed.